# como ponerle botones a un overflow

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

tengo un div que contiene imagenes y lleva un overflow, sucede que por defecto el navegador le da la barra de desplazamiento y quiero que tenga los botones de adelante y atras.

**como lo tengo:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**como lo quiero:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿como le añado los botones ?

Comment: A que boton te referis?Al del camion o al del simbolo a la  derecha?

Comment: quiero quitar la barra que da por defecto el navegador en el overflow y cambiarlo por botones que hagan mover el 'carousel'

Comment: Lo que buscas crear es un slider o carousel, no puedes hacerlo solo con `overflow`, prueba a buscar información sobre ellos y, si tienes dudas de cómo funcionan, editar la pregunta con parte del código que hayas intentado para que podamos ayudarte. https://codepen.io/mephysto/pen/ZYVKRY <-- Aquí tienes un ejemplo

Comment: Mira, aca te dejo un par https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/542/top-7-best-jquery-image-and-content-sliders-plugins
Fíjate que hay bastantes y proba hasta encontrar uno que se adecue a tus necesidades.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Poniendo la propiedad **overflow:hidden** oculta las barras de desplazamiento pero también evita que los elementos se muestren fuera del espacio contenedor. 
Primero valora si realmente necesitas ese overflow, y si es así coloca los botones de los lados dentro del espacio del contendor. 
Sin código no veo cual es el problema, siempre podrías colocarlos con posiciones absolutas y el contenedor relativo.